# How to write MATLAB code to find the answer of the equation with given all values of its variables?

Tags: matlab

I'm practicing MATLAB. and I stuck with this problem.

Suppose I have  Equation in general form like this

$d = ab + AB^2 + abB$

I have all values of its variable $a = 1 , b=2, A=4 ,B=6$

How to write MATLAB code to get the answer of this equation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: this is not an equation. This is an expression. Write in MATLAB what you have written in LaTex

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra I mean I want to find the value of d  when I can change the value of a,b,A,B. But I do not know how to do this.

Comment: You have to define a,b,A,B and then calculate $d=a*b+a*B^2+a*b*B$